# Is Claims-based authentication Required for Kerberos and Excel Services?

Tags: 2010, authentication, excel, powerpivot

I'm trying to setup Kerberos for Excel Services + SSAS. SharePoint Web Application pool using Classic Authentication. I was wondering if it's necessary to switch it to claims-based. I've found zero information on whether claims is a must in my case. Can someone, please, shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think Claims is must go for Kerberos. In SharePoint 2013 it is by default but in SharePoint 2010 their is no such restriction.

You can use both Claims as well as Classic.

In order to Configure the ECS with Kerberos, here are the steps:

1. Create Excel Services service account.
2. Configure a service principal name (SPN) on the Excel Services
   service account.
3. Configure Kerberos constrained delegation for Excel Services.
4. Start the Excel Services service instance on the Excel Services
   server.
5. Create the Excel Services service application and application proxy
   to enable web applications to process Excel Services.
6. Configure the location of the Excel Services trusted file and the
   authentication settings.
7. Grant the Excel Services service account permissions on the web
   application content database.

Source: [How to configure Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2010 for Kerberos authentication](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2466519/?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: Thank you Waqas. Do you have hands-on experienc on configuring Kerberos for Excel Services? If so - could I contact you somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, "you have setup Kerberos authentication for Excel + SSAS in SharePoint but not in IIS Pool and wondering if its necessary to set it to claim based in IIS pool or it should work with the classic mode?"

In this case i would recommend you to have a look [here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662541(v=office.14).aspx) . It may help you to understand.

Comment: Chillax, thank you for the link. I've read quite a lot on this topic, but still unsure whether SharePoint Application needs to use claims or not. If it's possible - could you, please provide the answer here instead of giving a link with general information?